# React - How can I wait for the UI to update after multiple api calls?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and need some help.

I've created a Pokedex and the app generates data from an API call, but then it needs to do another API call to get more data and then the same process ones more.

In my case the user needs to press the button three times to generate the "complete" information.

Can I need to use the "useEffect" hook that's implemented in React to solve this, if so, how?

Current code:

```
    import Axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function PK() {
  const api = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/",
  });

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({});
  const [pokemonDescription, fetchDescription] = useState({});
  const [evolution, pokemonEvolution] = useState({});

  const searchPokemon = () => {
    api.get(`pokemon/magnemite`).then((response) => {
      setPokemon({
        name: response.data.name,
        height: response.data.height,
        weight: response.data.weight,
        img: response.data.sprites.front_default,
        id: response.data.id,
        type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
        type2: response.data.types[1].type.name,
      });

      api.get(`pokemon-species/${pokemon.id}/`).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.evolution_chain);
        fetchDescription({
          entry: response.data.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text,
          evolution: response.data.evolution_chain.url,
        });
        api.get(`${pokemonDescription.evolution}`).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name);
          pokemonEvolution({
            evolution: response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name,
          });
        });
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{pokemon.name}</h1>
      <h1>#{pokemon.id}</h1>
      <h1>{pokemon.weight / 10} Kg</h1>
      <h1>{pokemon.height * 10} Cm</h1>
      <img src={pokemon.img} alt="" />
      <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        Type: {pokemon.type} {pokemon.type2}
      </h1>
      <h2 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        {pokemonDescription.entry}
      </h2>
      <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        Evolution: {evolution.evolution}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={searchPokemon}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default PK;
```

First click:[image]

Second click:[image]

Third click:[image]

So, I don't know how to create a good solution for making the calls simultaneously or to update the UI once all the calls has been made.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern you are calling your function

```
api.get().then(res1 => {
   setPokemon({...})
   api.get(pokemon.id).then(res2 => {
     set...
   })
})
```

The problem with your code is that you are assuming that as soon as your setPokemon has ended pokemon will have the value so you are calling it but, that is not how it works. For now just know that the pokemon state will have its value after the function completely executes.
If you want to know further how it works start that from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=4s

Now what I did is I took the response which is already present inside that block and passed the id from response.

```
api.get().then(res1 => {
   setPokemon({...}) // res1 is available here
   api.get(res1.data.id).then(res2 => {
     set... // res2 is available here
   })
})
```

Also there are multiple ways of doing same thing. So keep learning.
I also changed your code for a single state so you dont have to call setState everytime.

```
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({});

  const searchPokemon = async () => {
    let data = []
    await api.get(`pokemon/magnemite`).then(async (response) => {
      data.push({
        name: response.data.name,
        height: response.data.height,
        weight: response.data.weight,
        img: response.data.sprites.front_default,
        id: response.data.id,
        type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
        type2: response.data.types[1].type.name
      });
      await api.get(`pokemon-species/${response.data.id}/`).then(async (response) => {
        data.push({
          entry: response.data.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text,
        });
        await api
          .get(`${response.data.evolution_chain.url}`)
          .then((response) => {
            data.push({
              evolution: response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name
            });
          });
      });
    });
    data.map((item) => setPokemon(prev => ({...prev, ...item})))
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{pokemon.name}</h1>
      <h1>#{pokemon.id}</h1>
      <h1>{pokemon.weight / 10} Kg</h1>
      <h1>{pokemon.height * 10} Cm</h1>
      <img src={pokemon.img} alt="" />
      <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        Type: {pokemon.type} {pokemon.type2}
      </h1>
      <h2 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        {pokemon.entry}
      </h2>
      <h1 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
        Evolution: {pokemon.evolution}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={searchPokemon}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
```

If you like the answer please Up Vote. It is just for the sake of Stack Overflow XD. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the time you took to help me, I appreciate it a ton!
I tried and upvote, but I need 15reputation for it to be propper (sitting at 11 right now).

But again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchPokemon = () => {
    api.get(`pokemon/magnemite`).then((response) => {
      setPokemon({
        name: response.data.name,
        height: response.data.height,
        weight: response.data.weight,
        img: response.data.sprites.front_default,
        id: response.data.id,
        type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
        type2: response.data.types[1].type.name
      });
      api.get(`pokemon-species/${response.data.id}/`).then((response) => {
        fetchDescription({
          entry: response.data.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text,
          evolution: response.data.evolution_chain.url
        });
        api.get(`${response.data.evolution_chain.url}`).then((response) => {
          pokemonEvolution({
            evolution: response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name
          });
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

Replace your search function with this and it will run just fine.

Comment: Hey Prakhar, that's fantastic, it works like a charm.
I just wonder how this works, cant the responses be fetched from other calls instead of storing them in the setState?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Ribz Sorry mate but I didn't get what you want to ask but I am assuming you want to know why my code works.

Comment: @Ribz I added another answer hope it helps.